# Upgrading AWS Elastic Beanstalk from PHP 5.6 to 7.4 caused 'php_value' error in .htaccess logs

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just upgraded from AWS Elastic Beanstalk from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.4, but now I am getting errors in the logs related to .htaccess and `php_value` being unrecognized. How are these related?

Update:
Since fixed the problem but the error was more or less:

```
.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you moved from Elastic Beanstalk's PHP 5.6 AMI you also moved from Amazon Linux to Amazon Linux 2 and from using

```
Apache + mod_php
```

to using

```
nginx + FastCGI Process Manager (FPM)
```

by default.

You can configure your new setup to use Apache instead of nginx, but that still leaves you with FPM instead of mod_php. mod_php, being run as part of Apache, let you use php.ini directives like `php_value` in the Apache .htaccess files. FPM does not let you do this, so you need to either remove those directives or move them to php.ini (or the equivalent Elastic Beanstalk extension/override mechanism), or translate the settings into the equivalent FPM settings, (though FPM seems to support all the php.ini directives in its config file already).